# EF Core 7: The INSERT statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint during SAVECHANGES

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm having a problem with inserting a parent and child as part of a single SaveChanges().

Below are my two tables:

```
Company {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<User> Users { get; } = new List<User>();
}

User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; } = null!
}
```

I'm using FluentApi to map the relationship:

```
builder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("users", "dbo");
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Company).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId);
});
```

The code I used is:

```
var company = new Company()
{
    Name = "ABC"
}

_dbContext.Add(company);

var user = new User()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith",
    Email = "John.smith@gmail.com"
}
company.Users.Add(user);

_dbContext.Add(user);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I call SaveChanges() I get an error:

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Users_Companies_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in database "EFCore_Demo", table "dbo.Companies", column "Id".

The SQL being generated in the Output console is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Companies (Name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (@p0)

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (CompanyId, Email, FirstName, LastName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A company with the id '0' exists in your db? If not you will have to provide a valid company Id or you need to make CompanyId property nullable

Comment: You're not providing an ID for the Company object when creating it, so first of all you either need to provide one or ensure the database is generating them automatically. Next, you need to find out what the company ID is (if you didn't assign it yourself), and provide it when creating the User object.

Comment: @madmonk46 The CompanyId is mapped as a Foreign Key on the User. When the Company is inserted it is an Identity column and automatically generates an Id. Isn't the Id supposed to be automatically assigned by EF to the User due to the mapping or due to the fact that User lives inside a collection on the Company?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was not only adding the parent to the dbContext but also adding the children. As such, the children added alone do not have foreign keys, so the solution is to simply add your children to your parent object, and then ONLY "add" your parent to the dbContext.

[image: The problem]